# Get one specific token of string in C

Tags: c, strtok

I have a file that has text inside it (`<tab>` is `\t`):

```
display <tab> output_stmt
[ <tab> left_bracket
"Hello World" <tab> string_const
] <tab> right_bracket
~ <tab> term_sym
```

How can I get the strings after the `<tab>`, skipping the first string and `<tab>` everyline.

I only know how to get only the first string and ignore the rest of the line by using:

```
strtok(variablename, "\t");
```

Any useful answers are much appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you try something so far ? It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: You can read the file character by character. Keep a flag that tells you whether you want to print a char after reading it or not. This flag is switched on when you've read a tab and it is switched off when you've read a new-line character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `strtok()` function you can get also the next token. See the [man page of `strtok()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok):

> The  `strtok()`  function breaks a string into a sequence of zero or more nonempty tokens. On the first call to `strtok()` the string to be parsed should be specified in `str`. In each subsequent call that should  parse the same string, `str` must be `NULL`.

So you can call:

```
char* tokenOne = strtok(variablename, "\t"); /* first token  */
char* tokenTwo = strtok(NULL, "\t");         /* second token */
```

Note that you don't have to free memory because `strtok()` works with the input buffer as it changes it e.g.:

```
"display \t output_stmt\0"
```

will be:

```
"display \0 output_stmt\0"
```

after the call of `strtok()`. After that it just returns a pointer to the next token.

Comment: Oh I see, Thank you